# CASE RETORNANDO MAIS DE UMA LINHA EM UMA SUBCONSULTA

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou com um problema em uma subconsulta que me retornar o tipo do pagamento (CREDITO OU DEBITO)
e se o pagamento foi em cartão ou não.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porem, se eu tiver um pagamento com os dois tipos de cartão a subconsulta vai retornar dois registros e vai acabar quebrando, o que eu poderia fazer pra quando tiver dois tipos de pagamento eu considerar apenas um, no meu caso queria considerar apenas o credito.

Considero comissões através do tipo do pagamento; CREDITO + DEBITO = CREDITO (quero montar um case caso um dos tipos foi credito ele considere apenas o credito como tipo de pagamento)

segue o consegui fazer:

```
CASE 
        WHEN X.cartao = 'S' AND X.tipo = 'CREDITO' THEN 'CREDITO'
        WHEN X.cartao = 'S' AND X.tipo = 'DEBITO'  THEN 'DEBITO'
        WHEN X.cartao = 'S' AND X.tipo = 'CREDITO' AND X.tipo = 'DEBITO' THEN 'CREDITO' -- 
   ELSE 'N' END cartao,
```

Comment: Inclua seu `SQL`, somente seu `CASE` não faz sentido algum.

Comment: É impossível que `X.tipo = 'CREDITO'` e `X.tipo = 'DEBITO'` simultaneamente e portanto esta terceira condição nunca será satisfeita. Como você não explicou suficientemente como estão organizados seus dados talvez possam existir múltiplas linhas em sua tabela, uma para cada cartão?

Answer (score 2):

Bom dia,

Acho que uma alternativa seria utilizar *Top(1)* com *Order by* dentro da subconsulta. Como 'CREDITO' vem antes de 'DEBITO' em ordem ascendente, a subconsulta deverá retornar 'CREDITO' quando existirem os 2 tipos de cartão. Ex:

```
(
  select top(1)
    CASE 
        WHEN X.cartao = 'S' AND X.tipo = 'CREDITO' THEN 'CREDITO'
        WHEN X.cartao = 'S' AND X.tipo = 'DEBITO'  THEN 'DEBITO'
        WHEN X.cartao = 'S' AND X.tipo = 'CREDITO' AND X.tipo = 'DEBITO' THEN 'CREDITO' -- 
        ELSE 'N' 
    END cartao,
    -- ...

  order by cartao
)
```

Espero que ajude